# Merge multiple tables and join the same column with comma split

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, merge

I have about 15 csv files with the same number of unique IDs. And for each of the file the `col1` contains different text. How can I join them together to create a new table contains all the information from those 15 files? I tried to use `pd.merge`, create a new `col1` comma split those text and delete the duplicates `col1`. There will be some columns named `col1_x`,`col1_y`, `col1_y`,etc.. Is there any other better ways to implement this?

My input is,

```
df1:
ID   col1    location    gender
1    Airplane   NY         F
2    Bus        CA         M
3    NaN        FL         M
4    Bus        WA         F

df2:   
ID   col1    location    gender
1    Apple      NY         F
2    Peach      CA         M
3    Melon      FL         M
4    Banana     WA         F

df3: 
ID   col1    location    gender
1    NaN        NY         F
2    Football   CA         M
3    Boxing     FL         M
4    Running    WA         F
```

Expected output is,

```
ID   col1                location    gender
1    Airplane,Apple         NY         F
2    Bus,Peach,Football     CA         M
3    Melon,Boxing           FL         M
4    Bus,Banana,Running     WA         F
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) + [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
merged = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], sort=False)
result = merged.dropna().groupby(['location', 'gender'], as_index=False).agg({'col1' : ','.join}).reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
  location gender                col1
0       CA      M  Bus,Peach,Football
1       FL      M        Melon,Boxing
2       NY      F      Airplane,Apple
3       WA      F  Bus,Banana,Running
```

Answer (score 0):

For your data, you can do:

```
(pd.concat(df.melt(id_vars='ID').dropna() for df in [df1,df2,df3])
    .groupby(['ID','variable'])['value'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.unique()))
    .unstack()
)
```

Output:

```
variable                col1 gender location
ID                                          
1             Airplane,Apple      F       NY
2         Bus,Peach,Football      M       CA
3               Melon,Boxing      M       FL
4         Bus,Banana,Running      F       WA
```